# Testing SSO idp to sp. OpenAM

Tags: single-sign-on, openam

Good morning !

I am using openAM 10.1, and I am trying to debug my configuration.
So I am using openAM as a hosted sp, and our partners are remote identity providers.

The problem I have is that I do not want to have to ask our partner to send us request in order to test our configuration - Or at least try to minimize it !

So I though that idpSSOInit.jsp will be the answer but I am not sure.

That's what I tried :

```
    <form id="theform" action="https://ssotest.com/sp/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp" method="post">
        <div>
            <input 
                type="hidden" 
                name="SAMLResponse" 
value="PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6
cHJvdG9jb2wiIERlc3RpbmF0aW9uPSJodHRwczovL3Nzb3Rlc3QuaW5zcGlydXMuY29tOjQ0My9z
..."/>

            <input
                 type="hidden" 
                 name="metaAlias" 
                 value="/realm/sp"/>
            <input
                 type="hidden" 
                 name="NameIDFormat" 
                 value="transient"/>

            <input
                 type="hidden" 
                 name="RelayState" 
                 value="https://mysite.com"/>

            <input
                 type="hidden" 
                 name="binding" 
                 value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>

            <input
                 type="hidden" 
                 name="spEntityID" 
                 value="sso:realm:saml2"/>

        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
```

The SAMLResponse is what I got from our partner in the Federation log, and converted that to base 64.

But I am getting that error :

```
HTTP Status 400 - Error processing AuthnRequest. java.lang.NullPointerException

type Status report

message Error processing AuthnRequest. java.lang.NullPointerException

description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Error processing AuthnRequest. java.lang.NullPointerException).
```

And the Federation is giving me that :

```
ERROR: IDPSSOUtil.getIDPAuthnContextMapper: Unable to get IDP AuthnContext Mapper.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.meta.SAML2MetaUtils.getAttributes(SAML2MetaUtils.java:242)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getAttributeValueFromIDPSSOConfig(IDPSSOUtil.java:2351)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getIDPAuthnContextMapper(IDPSSOUtil.java:1260)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getAuthnStatement(IDPSSOUtil.java:1113)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getAssertion(IDPSSOUtil.java:814)
    ...


ERROR: Error processing request 
com.sun.identity.saml2.common.SAML2Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getIDPAuthnContextMapper(IDPSSOUtil.java:1288)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getAuthnStatement(IDPSSOUtil.java:1113)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getAssertion(IDPSSOUtil.java:814)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getResponse(IDPSSOUtil.java:729)
    ...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.meta.SAML2MetaUtils.getAttributes(SAML2MetaUtils.java:242)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getAttributeValueFromIDPSSOConfig(IDPSSOUtil.java:2351)
    at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.IDPSSOUtil.getIDPAuthnContextMapper(IDPSSOUtil.java:1260)
    ... 31 more
```

So, basically I would like to test manually what a partner is sending us so I can test my configuration and play around  and make sure everything is working fine. The only thing I need I believe is a saml response.

It should be possible right ?

Thank you for the help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Download the [SSO Tracer](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/sso-tracer/) Firefox addon. If you then run through the SAML exchange while the SSO Tracer logging window is open, it will show specific requests which have SAML data attached to them and also allow you to view the decoded SAML data.

To open the SSO Tracer window, hit ALT on the keyboard, open the Tools menu and select SSO Tracer.